# Preserving line breaks from text-area when sending mail

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a website where you can write and customize a mail then send it. I have a problem where the line breaks from a text-area doesn't preserve. When I send the mail with c#, there are no line breaks (sorry for my bad English, not my first language).

Here's my code:

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Web_Mail_Manager
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string YourUsername = "(Just gonna cover my Email)";
            string YourPassword = "(Just gonna cover my password)";

            string Destination = DestinationAdress.Value;
            string YourMessageSubject = MailSubject.Value;
            string YourMessageBody = MailBody.Value;

            try
            {
                using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587))
                {
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(YourUsername, YourPassword);
                    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage msgObj = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
                    msgObj.To.Add(Destination);
                    msgObj.From = new MailAddress(YourUsername);
                    msgObj.Subject = YourMessageSubject;
                    msgObj.Body = YourMessageBody;
                    msgObj.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    client.Send(msgObj);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Web_Mail_Manager.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: lightgray;
            font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
        }

        .mailPreview {
            background-color: white;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%);
            width: 45vw;
            height: fit-content;
            padding: 15px;
        }

        #MailBody {
            white-space: pre-wrap;
        }
        #MailbodyContent {
            white-space: pre-line;
        }
        #MailBody {
            white-space: pre-line;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function changeTo(val) {
            document.getElementById("toMail").innerHTML = val;
        }

        function changeSubject(val) {
            document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = val;
        }

        function changeBody(val) {
            var text = val;
            document.getElementById("MailbodyContent").textContent = text;
            document.getElementById("MailbodyContent").innerHTML.replace(/\n/g, '<br>\n');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input id="DestinationAdress" oninput="changeTo(value)" runat="server" type="text" placeholder="Recievers E-mail adress" /><br />
        <input id="MailSubject" oninput="changeSubject(value)" runat="server" type="text" placeholder="Subject" /><br />
        <textarea id="MailBody" oninput="changeBody(value)" runat="server" cols="40" rows="5" placeholder="Content"></textarea><br />
        <br />

        <div class="mailPreview" id="mailPreview">
            <h3>To: <span id="toMail"></span></h3>
            <h3>From: (Just gonna cover my email)</h3>
            <br />
            <h3>Subject: <span id="subject"></span></h3>
            <br />
            <h3>Content:</h3>
            <h4 runat="server" id="MailbodyContent"></h4>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
        </div>
        
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send mail!" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: Are you sending an HTML E-Mail? Because HTML will ignore the newline character and you need to replace it with a <br /> tag.

Comment: @mboldt I'm using c# to send the mail. I tried changing the whitespace to <br> tags, but c# wouldn't use those if that makes sense.

Comment: And if you set IsBodyHtml to false? Then it is regular text, using regular newlines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are sending HTML E-Mails (`msgObj.IsBodyHtml = true;`) you need to replace newlines with the `<br />` tag.

Replace the line
`string YourMessageBody = MailBody.Value;`

with

`string YourMessageBody = MailBody.Value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");`

Comment: But I'm using C# to send the mail. I just get the content from the HTML inputs.
I can display the content from the inputs with line breaks on the html page, but the c# code doesnt pick up the line breaks

Comment: When you display the mail body below your form you replace all newline characters with a <br /> tag in the changeBody-method. That's why it's displaying just fine. In your code example there is no replacements of the newline characters in the c# code